# JQuery animation ul list

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
<style>
.myNewsSlider
{
width:200px;
height:44px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
 }

 .myNewsList
 {
margin:0px; 
padding:0px;
position: absolute;
 }
</style>

<div class="myNewsSlider">
  <ul class="myNewsList">
    <li>first element</li>
    <li>second element</li>
    <li>third element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the list to move from bottom to top and show each element for 5 seconds.

The first element will show for 5 seconds, then disappear, and the second element will show for 5 seconds, etc.

How do I use Jquery to complete this task?

Comment: Q:How to use Jquery animate function to complete this task???? | A:By first learning how to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** much simpler : http://jsfiddle.net/aLprr/

APIs used:

- `.promise` - http://api.jquery.com/promise/
- `.delay` - http://api.jquery.com/delay/
- `.fadeOut` - http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=.fadeOut&go=

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

P.S. - play around with the 5000 calculation.

**Code**

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(4000 * index).fadeOut(500).promise(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });


});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var p;
for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
  p=i*20;
  $('.myNewsList').animate({"margin-top":"-"+p+"px"},1000).delay(5000);
 }​

.myNewsSlider
 {
  width:200px;
  height:24px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
```

}

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HsTcf/4/)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to

1]set myNewsList's `li`'s `margin-top` property to `100%`;

2]Tell jquery to `animate` myNewsList's `li` by making its `margin-top` to `0%`

3]for the `5 seconds` delay,you can use the  `setInterval()` method where you can hide the first li  of myNewsList after every 5 seconds and then animate the second `li` by setting it's `top-margin` to 0%.If all li's are hidden,again start from the first `li`..